# What is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined for AppBar + Drawer component (ReactJS + Material-UI)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drawer, material-ui, appbar

I am attempting to get the navigation, default hamburger icon on the left of AppBar ( http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar ) from Material-UI framework to slide open the Drawer component when clicked ( http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/drawer ). But once clicked, I am getting the following error and I can't see to figure out:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Any insight or guidance on it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Drawer, AppBar, MenuItem} from 'material-ui'
import baseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/lightBaseTheme'
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme'
import { Route, Router } from 'react-router'



export default class Main extends Component  {

  constructor(props, context){
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {open:false};
  }

  getChildContext() {
    return {muiTheme: getMuiTheme(baseTheme)};
  }

  handleToggle() {
    this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
   }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                <AppBar   
                  isInitiallyOpen={true} 
                  onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.handleToggle}        
                  onLeftIconButtonClick={this.handleToggle} 
                />

                <Drawer
                  docked={false}
                  open={this.state.open}>
                  <MenuItem>Menu Item 1</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem>Menu Item 3</MenuItem>
                </Drawer>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

export default Main;
```

Comment: What version of React are you using? What is most likely happening is that your version of React doesn't autobind handler functions to the component meaning that the `this` value in `handleToggle` is not the component and thus `this.state` is undefined. If thats the case, to fix this, you can put `this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this)` in the `constructor`.

Comment: Thx, this solved the issue for me

Comment: This solved the issue for me too!

Answer (score 0):

You can also make function component instead of class componnet.It will make your component crisp and more readable -

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Drawer, AppBar, MenuItem } from 'material-ui'
import baseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/lightBaseTheme'
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme'
import { Route, Router } from 'react-router'



export default function Main(props) {

    let [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    let handleToggle = () => {
        setOpen(!open);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <AppBar
                isInitiallyOpen={true}
                onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={handleToggle}
                onLeftIconButtonClick={handleToggle}
            />

            <Drawer
                docked={false}
                open={open}>
                <MenuItem>Menu Item 1</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem>Menu Item 3</MenuItem>
            </Drawer>
        </div>
    );
}
```