# Implementing a Drawer & AppBar with Material-UI + React {Cannot read property 'open' of null}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

So I'm trying to use `React` & `Material-UI` to create an app, so I managed to get the AppBar up and running but am having some issues getting the Drawer to work.

I keep getting an `error: cannot read property open of null`, and have tried to figure out what the issue is to with no success. I found a 2 post on Stack about this exact issue, both of them don't have an answer that was able to resolve my problem

[Having trouble using Appbar + Drawer (Material UI + ReactJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38429024/having-trouble-using-appbar-drawer-material-ui-reactjs)

[What is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined for AppBar + Drawer component (ReactJS + Material-UI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37357512/what-is-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-open-of-undefined-for-appbar)

This is my current code:

```js
constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this)
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this)
    this.setState = {
      open: false
    };
  }

  handleToggle = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});

  handleClose = () => this.setState({open: false});

  render() {
    return <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
        <AppBar
          onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.handleToggle}
          onLeftIconButtonClick={this.handleToggle}
          title="How long have you been alive?"
          iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more" />
        <Drawer
          docked={false}
          width={200}
          open={this.state.open}
          onRequestChange={(open) => this.setState({open})}
        >
          <MenuItem onTouchTap={this.handleClose}>Menu Item 1</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onTouchTap={this.handleClose}>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
        </Drawer>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
  }
```

(snippit isn't suppose to run, just show my relevant code)

I thought maybe binding `this` to `render` would help, but it did not :(

Comment: `this.render = this.render.bind(this)` remove this and add `this.handleToggle = this. handleToggle.bind(this)` and same for other function in constructor method

Comment: So I tried that before, and still got the same error (gave it another try now and still nothing). It seems the error is coming from `open={this.state.open}`. Not sure what is causing it to fail though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in your code is you are not setting state in constructor. `this.setState` in constructor is wrong, it needs to be replaced with `this.state`

```
constructor() {
    super();
    //...other lines of codes that you may intend to write

    this.state = {
      open: false
    };

  }
```

`this.setState()` is a method that you call to update component's state from any method of a Component-Class except `render()` and `constructor()`

Comment: I edited the code above to show you what I currently have.

(Not sure what you mean by other lines of code, I'm sorry)

Comment: Okay! I made the edits, and now I'm running into a different error. It now says `Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'children' of type 'array' supplied to 'MuiThemeProvider', expected a single ReactElement.`

It's wrapped in the `MuiThemeProvider` so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Edit* This error also comes up: `Invariant Violation: MuiThemeProvider.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

Comment: that means `MuiThemeProvider` wants to have only one child but you are giving it 2 `AppBar` and `Drawer`. Put Appbar and drawer inside a single div

Comment: WOOHOO! It works :) More importantly, I understand what happened and how it was fix. I can't thank you enough kind sir!